# Overload comparison operators for a templated class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having troubles in overloading comparison operators in order to compare two `pair` struct in such way:

```
typedef pair<string, unsigned int> INDEX;
bool operator>(INDEX &v1, INDEX &v2)
{
    if(v1.second == v2.second)  //if integer parts are equal
    {
        //string that comes earlier in the dictionary should be larger
        return v1.first < v2.first; 
    }
    return v1.second > v2.second;
}
```

The actual comparison takes place at `this->element(hole/2) < this->element(hole)` inside `fixUp(CBTNODE hole)`, a member function of `BinaryHeap` class, which is a derived class of `CompleteBinaryTree`. The `T` will be instantiated as type `INDEX`, which is `typedef`ed as `pair<string, unsigned int>`.

In other words, the comparison between two pairs: ("a.txt", 42) > ("b.txt", 42) should return true.

I tried to overload `operator>` outside the class declaration in two different ways but neither of them worked:

1. `bool operator>(INDEX &v1, INDEX &v2);`
2. `bool operator>(BinaryHeap<T> &v1, BinaryHeap<T> &v2);`

Any help will be much appreciated!

Z.Zen

Here is the declarations:

```
typedef int CBTNODE;

template <typename T>
class CompleteBinaryTree {
public:
  //Initializes an empty binary tree
  CompleteBinaryTree(int initialSize = 10);

  //Destructor
  ~CompleteBinaryTree();

  //Returns the element of the CBT pointed to by node. Behavior is undefined
  //if node does not exist. 
  T element(CBTNODE node);

protected:
  T *data;
  int numElts, maxElts;
};

typedef pair<string, unsigned int> INDEX;

template <typename T>
class BinaryHeap : public CompleteBinaryTree<T>
{
    public:
        //Maintain heap property with bottom up heapify method.
        void fixUp(CBTNODE hole);
};
bool operator>(INDEX &v1, INDEX &v2);
```

Implementation:

```
template <typename T>
T CompleteBinaryTree<T>::element(CBTNODE node) {
  assert(node >= 0);
  assert(node < numElts);
  return data[node];
}

template <typename T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::fixUp(CBTNODE hole)
{
    T tmp = this->element(hole);    
    while( hole > 0 && this->element(hole/2) < tmp )
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

bool operator>(INDEX &v1, INDEX &v2)
{
    if(v1.second == v2.second)  //if two have same relevance
    {
        return v1.first < v2.first;
    }
    return v1.second > v2.second;
}
```

Comment: what error do you get and at which line?

Comment: Is there a real need to define 'bool operator>(INDEX &v1, INDEX &v2);'. Doesn't pair class have comparison operators?

Comment: It compiled but it didn't do what it supposed to do. I created a test case that does the comparison: pair<'a', 42> > pair<'b', 42> and it returns false, which is supposed to return true according to my definition. The first element of the pair is a c++ string and second element is a int.

Comment: 'a' and 'b' are chars, not strings.  You are not invoking your function.  You are invoking (pair<char,int> > pair<char,int>)

Comment: So your code output depends on the comparison 'return v1.first < v2.first;'. What are 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: @Chubsdad Yes, pair does overload the comparison operators. But when I compare the string, I want the "less" string to appear as "greater". In other words, ("a", 42) is greater than ("b", 42), which is the opposite of what the default comparison operators do.

Comment: @Chubsdad oops, my bad. What I meant for "a" and "b" are c++ strings.

Comment: @Z.Zen -- What exactly does the code look like where you create and compare your pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary, such as the result of `element` func, cannot be bound to a reference to non-`const`, such as the formal arguments of your `operator>`.

Declare it thusly:

```
bool operator>( INDEX const& v1, INDEX const& v2 )
```

However, the implementation that you present doesn't seem to be correct for `operator>`.

And while I'm at it, what you want is really `operator<` instead, because that's the one required by standard algorithms. Perhaps combined with an `operator==` (because it's inefficient to synthesize it from `operator<`). With those two any relationship can be checked for relatively efficiently.

Btw., if you stop using ALL UPPERCASE names for anything else then macros (see the FAQ), then you can avoid inadvertent name collision with macros.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: thank you so much! It works like a charm. I actually implemented all comparison operators but I only showed one in my question for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Hmm. It did not strike me about the 'const &' as the OP mentioned that the code builds and runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't typedef INDEX, be explicit:

```
template<class F, class S>
struct Index {
    std::pair<F, S> Value;
    Index(const std::pair<F, S>& pValue)
     : Value(pValue) {}
};

template<class F, class S>
bool operator<(const Index<F, S>& pLeft, const Index<F, S>& pRight) {
    // your implementation...
}
```